# How to tell any Queue to Mockito using ArgumentMatchers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock the following method:

```
@Override
public void handleStorage(TradeItem tradeItem,
                          ProductImagesMap productImagesMap,
                          List<Integer> indicesToProcess,
                          int countProductImages,
                          Queue<EcomImageMetadata> ecomImageMetadataQueue,
                          ImageServiceType imageServiceType,
                          ProductImageDTO productImageDTO) throws IllegalAccessException {
```

and this is how I am trying:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;

final Class<Integer> integerClazz = Integer.class;
final Class<EcomImageMetadata> ecomImageMetadataClazz = EcomImageMetadata.class;
Mockito.when(productImageStorageService.handleStorage(eq(mockTradeItem), eq(productImagesMap), anyListOf(integerClazz), anyInt(), anyIterableOf(ecomImageMetadataClazz), anyObject(), anyObject()))
            .thenReturn(null);
```

I do not understand why `anyListOf(integerClazz)` works but `anyIterableOf(ecomImageMetadataClazz)` is causing:

```
Error:(157, 152) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.lang.Iterable<T> conforms to java.util.Queue<org.gs1ca.dar.domain.EcomImageMetadata>
```

How do I match the Queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the generic version of the argument matcher `ArgumentMatchers.any()`. In version java up to 7 you need to specify the type like this:

```
ArgumentMatchers.<Queue<EcomImageMetadata>>any()
```

If you are using java 8+ just use: `ArgumentMatchers.any()`.